# prestashop: How to display accessories of a product if product has properties?

Tags: smarty

In product.tpl below code needs some more effective conditions.

```
{if $features}
<section class="page_product_box toggle_frame datasheet" style="display:none;">
    <h3 class="toggle">{l s='Data sheet'}<i class="icon-toggle icon-minus-sign-alt"></i></h3>
    <div class="features">
                              {if isset($features) && $features}
                                    {foreach from=$features item=feature}

                               <div id="feature-icon"><img class="feature" title="{$feature.detail}" src="{$img_ps_dir}f/{$feature["id_feature"]}.jpg" width="65" height="65"/></div>                                       
                                    {/foreach}
    </div>

</section>
{/if}
```